# Rails: Undefined local variable or method `form' in rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my _form partial I render another partial like below

```
<%= render :partial => 'test', :object => @application.type, \
              :locals => {:form => form, \
              :application_type => "application[type]"} %>
```

When I try to load the form I get this error

```
undefined local variable or method `form' for #<#<Class:0x6daf2c8>:0x8dd3c80>
```

My test partial

```
<%= fields_for application_type, application do |application_f| %>
    <div>
      <div>
        <%= application_f.label :uni_id, "University" %>
        <%= application_f.collection_select :uni_id, @unis, :id, :check, {:include_blank => true} %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>         

<% end %>
```

I recently updated to rails 4.1 from 3.2. It was working before but now it shows error. I guess it is syntax error but could not solve it.

Comment: You don't seem to use form anywhere in the partial.  What is around your render partial call?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to replace something like this, in your top-level template:

```
<%= render partial: "form", form: form %>
```

or like this:

```
<%= render partial: "form", object: form %>
```

with something like this (the *locals* parameter is required now)

```
<%= render partial: "form", locals: { form: form } %>
```

Comment: I am working on a old project. I don't find the use of form. There are two models which are associated with this model and autosave = true.

Comment: something must call your form partial, maybe that's another partial, maybe a top-level view, maybe it's called in some fancy way directly from the controller, but there must be a caller. And it probably either doesn't pass the form object, either pass it in a wrong way. Generally you should see the caller from the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few errors:

```
<%= render partial: 'test', locals: {form: form }, object: @application %>

<%= form.fields_for application.type, application do |application_f| %>
    <div>
      <div>
        <%= application_f.label :uni_id, "University" %>
        <%= application_f.collection_select :uni_id, @unis, :id, :check, {:include_blank => true} %>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>         
<% end %>
```

This *should* provide the correct syntax for you.

The *error* is down to the `form` variable not being populated. This seems to be from the `<%= render` call. Without context, the best fix I can give is *how* it should look:

```
<%= form_for @variable do |form| %>
   <%= render partial: "test", locals: {form:form}, object: @application %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this same issue when working on a **Rails 6** application

I did an overriding of my routes due to some conflicts from

```
resources :sessions
```

to

```
resources :sessions, as: :sets
```

**Here's how I fixed it**:

**app/views/sessions/new.html.erb**

```
<h1>New Session</h1>

<%= form_with(model: @session, url: sets_path, local: true) do |form| %>
  <%= render partial: 'form', session: @session, locals: { form: form } %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', sets_path %>
```

**Note**: A URL was defined for the New Form since routing override was done. Thus, the form_with container was isolated from the `_form.html.erb` partial. This is in a bid to avoid creating multiple `_form.html.erb` partials for the `new.html.erb` and `edit.html.erb files`, since they have different URLs.

**app/views/sessions/edit.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with(model: @session, url: set_path(@session), local: true) do |form| %>
  <%= render partial: 'form', session: @session, locals: { form: form } %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Show', set_path(session) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', sets_path %>
```

**Note**: A URL was defined for the New Form since routing override was done. Thus, the form_with container was isolated from the `_form.html.erb` partial. This is in a bid to avoid creating multiple `_form.html.erb` partials for the `new.html.erb` and `edit.html.erb files`, since they have different URLs.

**app/views/sessions/_form.html.erb**

```
<% if @session.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@session.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this session from being saved:</h2>

    <ul>
      <% @session.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
  <%= form.label :name %>
  <%= form.text_field :name %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= form.label :prefix %>
  <%= form.text_field :prefix %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
  <%= form.submit %>
</div>
```

**Note**: Notice that there is no form helper definition in the `_form.html.erb` file, it was moved to the `new.html.erb` and `edit.html.erb` files, since they now have different URLs due to the modification of their route.

**app/views/sessions/index.html.erb**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Sessions</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Prefix</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @sessions.each do |session| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= session.name %></td>
        <td><%= session.prefix %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', set_path(session) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_set_path(session) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', set_path(session), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Session', new_set_path %>
```

**Note**: Pay attention to the modification of the link URLs in the `new` action.

**app/views/sessions/show.html.erb**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @session.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Prefix:</strong>
  <%= @session.prefix %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_session_path(@session) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', sessions_path %>
```

**Note**: Pay attention to the modification of the link URLs in the `edit` and `back` actions.

**app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_session, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /sessions
  # GET /sessions.json
  def index
    @sessions = Session.all
  end

  # GET /sessions/1
  # GET /sessions/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /sessions/new
  def new
    @session = Session.new
  end

  # GET /sessions/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /sessions
  # POST /sessions.json
  def create
    @session = Session.new(session_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @session.save
        format.html { redirect_to sets_path(@sesion), notice: 'Session was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: sets_path(@sesion) }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @session.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /sessions/1
  # PATCH/PUT /sessions/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @session.update(session_params)
        format.html { redirect_to sets_path(@sesion), notice: 'Session was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: sets_path(@sesion) }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @session.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /sessions/1
  # DELETE /sessions/1.json
  def destroy
    @session.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to sets_url, notice: 'Session was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_session
      @session = Session.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def session_params
      params.require(:session).permit(:name, :prefix)
    end
end
```

**Note**: Pay attention to the modification of the redirect URLs in the `create` and `update` actions.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**